# GitLab CI pipeline stopped working with invalid yaml error after upgrading to 16.1.5

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I had a GitLab CI pipeline which suddenly stopped working after upgrading to GitLab 16.1.5 from 16.0.2.

I get the following error message on the merge request now:

```
Unable to create pipeline
image is defined in top-level and `default:` entry
```

I didn't change anything in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Pipeline gives `invalid yaml` error.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to move the `image:` keyword under the `default:` keyword.

Before:

```
image:
  name: alpine:3.17
```

After:

```
default:
  image: alpine:3.17
```

Seems like they might have deprecated the image keyword on top-level and moved it under the default keyword in older versions and completely made it unavailable on top-level in latest versions.

References:

- [GitLab CI/CD - Template Types](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html#template-types:%7E:text=Place%20any%20global%20keywords%20like%20image%20or%20before_script%20in%20a%20default%20section%20at%20the%20top%20of%20the%20template)
- [.gitlab-ci.yml keyword reference - Global keywords](https://docs.gitlab.com/16.2/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#global-keywords)